# how can i get pixel of an image in UIimageView by calling a touchEvent on an imageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, touch-event, getpixel

I want to call an touchEvent on an imageView.On touch of a imageView,i want to get a pixel of an Image.I am using this:-

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
[sampleImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if ([touch view] == sampleImage) 
{

    url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Na.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    [sampleImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:10.0/255.0 blue:10.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
NSError *error;
audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:&error];
audio.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audio play];
[sampleImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];   
}
```

Is it possible?if Yes then Please Help.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: see `userInteractionEnabled` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a gesture recognizer to your imageview and let the delegate handle the sound playing for you.

In your viewDidLoad you implement the following:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [YourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
```

In your code you can put the delegate and the sound playing like:

```
- (void)tapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourSound" ofType:@"mp3"];

    AVAudioPlayer * theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
    [theAudio release];
}
```

There you go!

EDIT:

---

To use above option with touchesMoved implement the following:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        if ([touch view] == YourImageView) {
        //play the sound
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourSound" ofType:@"mp3"];

            AVAudioPlayer * theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
            theAudio.delegate = self;
            [theAudio play];
            [theAudio release];

        }
    }
```

There you go :)

Comment: can i use this method - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event????

Comment: Yeah absolutely, I shall edit my answer.

Comment: BarryK88:-can u pls tell me why my this question has been closed?

Comment: as i m new to iphone pls help me??

Comment: you should read the FAQ of stackoverflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` and can set `target` as your `imageview`:

[image]

Comment: can i use this method - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event????